# Magento custom template - edit lightbox sizing

Tags: magento

I am using a custom magento template which has a lightbox on the product page.  I can set the max width/height for the lightbox in the config as a percentage of the screen (ie 95%).  The problem is it then uses this as the default value so even it is is a really small image it will stretch it out to 95% of the screen and cause the image to pixelate.

I would like it to use this percentage as a maximum only but if the actual image is smaller than this then it would use the actual image dimensions.

I have found a file with this code which I think I may need to edit but I am not sure how to go about this in Magento:

```
<?php
    $maxWidth   = $zoomHelper->getCfg('lightbox/max_width');
    $maxHeight  = $zoomHelper->getCfg('lightbox/max_height');
    $cfg = '';
    if ($maxWidth)
        $cfg .= ", maxWidth:'{$maxWidth}'";
    if ($maxHeight)
        $cfg .= ", maxHeight:'{$maxHeight}'";
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I found this code which could help however it only seems to work when used in the view.phtml file and not the file I am trying to edit.

$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->getOriginalHeight();

Answer (score 1):

The way I've done this is to load up relatively large images as the base product image. When the product / view is rendering, build a js object that contains urls for large images, and any thumbnails you need. Your lightbox should then use the js object as a data source.

**media.phtml**

```
<script> var images = {};</script>

<?php $_images = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
<?php if($_images){?>            
    <?php $i=0; foreach($_images as $_image){ $i++; ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(108,90); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" title="<?php $this->htmlEscape($_image->getLabel());?>" /><?php } ?>

        <script> images.bigsrc = "<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail', $_image->getFile())->resize(800,800); ?>"  </script>
    <?php } ?>
```

You then have a js object containing urls for whatever size image you would need. Pass that into lightbox / fancybox etc.

You will definitely have to tailor this to match your needs - mostly in terms of creating a js object that you can use.

Some info on resizing images in mage:
http://www.magthemes.com/magento-blog/customize-magentos-image-resize-functionality/

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have large enough images for some of the products so we need it to load the original size image without scaling it up if it is smaller than 95% of the screen.

Comment: ah. that's a problem. I'm sure there are methods of grabbing the original height (your code looks promising). I would still recommend constructing a data obj to pass to your lightbox.